# Paramagnetism of group 2 elements

Tags: magnetism

As far as I know, paramagnetism in normal substance arises due to unpaired electrons. I believe that the valence electrons of group 2 elements (Be, Mg, Ca, Sr, Ba) are paired.

But, [here](https://www.gemstonemagnetism.com/uploads/Magnetic_Susceptibilities_of_the_Elements.pdf) in the list of given compounds, all of the group 2 elements (except Be) have positive susceptibility, and it is specified in the same document that positive susceptibility implies paramagnetism.

My question:
How can these elements show paramagnetic behaviour?

Comment: When you have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding, you don't have the electrons paired the same way as you would with isolated atoms.  The real question may be why this _doesn't_ work for beryllium.  Lithium, the only other (ambient) metal in Period 2, is paramagnetic.

Comment: I suspected that, but I thought I was wrong. As I can't reason through the fact that why gallium is diamagnetic and aluminium is paramagnetic despite the fact that both have metallic bonding and both belongs to the same group, one hand-wavy thought might be that Gallium go extensive of it. And for Be, one thought might be Be is not-that metallic.